# Printing a hashtable

Tags: c

I have an assignment regarding some hashtable operations. The operations I should include are insert, find, delete and print the full table contents. The insert, delete and find seem to work just fine, but I can't understand why my print function doesn't work.  I get nothing printed really. (I will print in file after I solve this problem.)
Here are the functions(myfunctions.c, linked by the header myfunctions.h):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define B 26
#include "myfunctions.h"

int hashfunction(char *name){
int sum; unsigned long len;
sum = 0;
len = strlen(name);
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    sum+=name[i];
}
return (sum%26);
}

void fillNode(NodeT *p, char *value){
p->name=value;
}

void insert(NodeT **Bucket, char *name){

NodeT *p=(NodeT*)malloc(sizeof(NodeT));

if(p){
    fillNode(p, name);
    int h=hashfunction(p->name);

    if(Bucket[h]==NULL){
        Bucket[h]=p;
        p->next=NULL;
    }
    else {
        p->next=Bucket[h];
        Bucket[h]=p;
    }
}
}

NodeT *findNode(NodeT **buckets, char *str){
int ok=0;
int i=0;
NodeT *aux=(NodeT*)malloc(sizeof(NodeT));

for(i=0;i<B;i++){
    NodeT *p=buckets[i];
    while(p){
        if(strcmp(p->name, str)==0)
        {
            ok=1;
            aux=p;
        }
        p=p->next;
    }
}
if(aux!=NULL) return aux;
else return NULL;
}

void deleteNode(NodeT **buckets, char *str){

NodeT **link=&buckets[hashfunction(str)];

while(*link){
    NodeT *aux=*link;
    if(strcmp(aux->name, str)==0){
        *link=aux->next;
        free(aux);
        break;
    }
    else link=&(*link)->next;
}
}

void printNodes(NodeT **buckets){

int i=0;
for(i=0;i<B;i++){
    NodeT *p=buckets[23];
    while(p){
        printf("%s\n", p->name);
        p=p->next;
    }

}
}
```

And this is the main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "myfunctions.h"
#define B 26

int main() {

FILE *input=fopen("/Users/andreibrasoveanu/Desktop/Teme CP/lab 6 - hashtables/lab 6 - hashtables/input.txt", "r");
FILE *output=fopen("/Users/andreibrasoveanu/Desktop/Teme CP/lab 6 - hashtables/lab 6 - hashtables/output.txt", "w");

char cmd[100];
char s[100];

NodeT **Bucket=(NodeT**)malloc(B*sizeof(NodeT*));
for(int i=0; i<26; i++) {
    Bucket[i]=NULL;
}

int hashcode;
char c;

while(fscanf(input, "%s\n", cmd)!=-1){
    c=cmd[0];

    strcpy(s, cmd+1);

    switch (c) {
        case 'i':
        {
            hashcode=hashfunction(s);
            insert(Bucket, s);
        }
            break;

        case 'd':{
            deleteNode(Bucket, s);
        }
            break;

        case 'f':{
            if(findNode(Bucket, s)!=NULL) printf("%s was found", s);
        }
            break;
        case 'l':{
            printNodes(Bucket);
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}



return 0;
}
```

And also the header file(myfunctions.h):

```
typedef struct node{
char *name;
struct node *next;
}NodeT;

int hashfunction(char *name);
void insert(NodeT **Bucket, char *name);
NodeT *findNode(NodeT **buckets, char *str);
void deleteNode(NodeT **buckets, char *str);
void printNodes(NodeT **buckets);
```

Input file would be:

```
iBob
iMary
dBob
l
```

I work in Xcode btw, that's why the path for the files is so long.

Comment: `NodeT *p=buckets[23];` ---> `NodeT *p=buckets[i];`

Comment: yeah I fixed that, still doesn't work

Comment: Read this https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You use the same buffer as a `name`. It is become `""` by the last command.

Comment: I think that `void fillNode()` needs to duplicate the string instead of just storing the pointer since the name buffer will be used repeatedly.

Comment: That was the problem, it is now solved, thanks

Comment: Note that this means that `deleteNode()` should also `free(aux->name)` before the `free(aux)` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines of code is incorrect:

```
 void fillNode(NodeT *p, char *value){
    p->name=value;
 }
```

The structure element 'name' is a pointer to char but I don't see any memory allocated for this.  So it needs something like:

```
     p->name = strdup(value);
```

Also, you don't need curly brackets on each switch label:

```
    case 'i':
    {
        hashcode=hashfunction(s);
        insert(Bucket, s);
    }
        break;
```

can be

```
    case 'i':        
        hashcode=hashfunction(s);
        insert(Bucket, s);

        break;
```